# Variable Number of Object Elements based on an index

Tags: c#

These two lists can have up to four elements.  But if there are between 1 and 3 then this code will crash with an 'out of bounds' array index.  How can I make the number of elements in the declared object vary dynamically based on the Count of each List object.  I'm trying to avoid having a different function call for every combination.

```
  if (ListOne.Count > 0 && ListTwo.Count > 0)
    {
       Func_Name(new object[] { "@Old1",ListOne[0], 
                                "@Old2",ListOne[1], 
                                "@Old3",ListOne[2], 
                                "@Old4",ListOne[3],
                                "@New1",ListTwo[0], 
                                "@New2",ListTwo[1], 
                                "@New3",ListTwo[2], 
                                "@New4",ListTwo[3]);
    }
```

Comment: You could iterate over ListOne and ListTwo, and then dynamically add new objects to the object array.

Comment: But how would you name each element?